# How to convert an image into a Base64 string in a file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, base64

I want to select multiple images and convert them to Base64 strings. I pushed the files into one array. My requirement is that after converting into Base64 strings, I want to push them into an array. I am not able to convert the images to Base64 strings.

```js
$("input[name=property_images]").change(function() {
    var names = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < $(this).get(0).files.length; ++i) {
        names.push($(this).get(0).files[i].name);
    }
 console.log(names);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="property_images" multiple="multiple" />
```

Comment: I've done this with Angular before, and just warning you that if you have a image bigger than an icon than your browser experiences major problems handling a string as long as a base64. It crashed my chrome and I couldn't use the base64 method at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your function to store the base64 value

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name=property_images]").change(function() {
      var imgBase64Arr = [];
      var files = this.files;
      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        (function(i){
          var FR = new FileReader();
          FR.onload = function(e) {
            imgBase64Arr.push( e.target.result );//adding base64 value to array

            if(i === files.length -1)//after all files are porcessed
              submitData(imgBase64Arr)
          };
          FR.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
        })(i);
      }

    });

   function submitData(imgBase64Arr){
     console.log(imgBase64Arr);
   }
});
```

Comment: I tried your code Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined
    at FileReader.FR.onload

Comment: I tried now single file Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
    at FileReader.FR.onload

Comment: Mr azad , possible means make fiddle answer

Comment: @SagunthalaK isn't helpful to you?

Comment: @Kaiido it is just display the contents of the array after processed all images

Comment: @azad, it should not. FileReader.readAsXXX are async. Here you are logging an empty array, after it has logged this empty array, it will have time to process the load events, but it'll be too late.

Comment: @Kaiido Ok I updated my answer to display array after last file processed

Comment: Glad you got it ;-)

Comment: Thanks i got exact answer

Comment: How to use outside the loop in the variable imgBase64Arr,bcz i want pass in json array

Comment: you can use imgBase64Arr variable out side the after loaded all image data

Comment: Mr azad pls tell me , user select images and when click the submit button that time only i want like this

Comment: @SagunthalaK define a function which accept imgBase64Arr, call that function where `console.log(imgBase64Arr);` whith parameters

Answer (score 0):

Here we have single image to convert base64 string.

```js
function readFile() {
  if (this.files) {
    for(i=0;i<this.files.length;i++)
      {
    var FR= new FileReader();
    FR.onload = function(e) {
      //document.getElementById("img").src       = e.target.result;
      //document.getElementById("b64").innerHTML = e.target.result;
      //$("#b64").append("<div></div>").html(e.target.result);
      $('<img src="'+e.target.result+'" />').appendTo('#show-image');
      $('<p>'+e.target.result+'</p>').appendTo('#text-image');
    };       
    FR.readAsDataURL( this.files[i] );
  }
    }
}

document.getElementById("inp").addEventListener("change", readFile, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inp" type='file' multiple>


<div id='show-image'></div>

<div id='text-image'></div>
```

Comment: I need multiselect image

Comment: @Vijay don't just copy paste others answers

Comment: @azad Sorry for that. Now is it ok?